# Django REST Framework and generic relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Problem**

I have a model with the following standard generic foreign key fields:

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
event_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

According to REST framework's docs, I can do the following to serialise this correctly:

```
class WhateverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event_object = serializers.RelatedField(source='event_object')
```

This works fine, however in two other related situations, I can't get things working:

1. I would like to use `HyperlinkedRelatedField`. This field requires the view_name argument, something I can't declare since the view name varies with the related model. I solved this by using `SerializerMethodField`, instantiating a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` at runtime and returning its `field_to_native` method (see snippet below). This does not feel very elegant.
2. I would like to nest the related object directly in the serialisation by saying `event_object = SoAndSoSerializer(source='event_object')`. The only solution I can see is to walk every `*Serializer` I have defined and check which has the correct model, then use that. Again, this does not feel very elegant.

**Questions**

is HyperlinkRelatedField meant to work across a generic relationship? Am I just making a mistake? Is there an obvious solution to picking the right `*Serializer` that I'm missing?

**Code Snippet**

The inelegant solution mentioned in bullet point 1 above:

```
class WhateverSerializer(DefaultSerializer):

    event_object_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_related_object_url')
    # ...

    def get_related_object_url(self, obj):
        obj = obj.event_object
        default_view_name = '%(model_name)s-detail'
        format_kwargs = {
            'app_label': obj._meta.app_label,
            'model_name': obj._meta.object_name.lower()
        }
        view_name = default_view_name % format_kwargs
        s = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(source=obj, view_name=view_name)
        s.initialize(self, None)
        return s.field_to_native(obj, None)
```

Comment: Note that you only need to use the 'source' argument for a field if the source is different from the field name. You can drop it in the 'event_object' case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your right, REST framework doesn't support those use cases, and its not obvious to me what the design would look like if it did. You'd probably need an implicit registry of model->view (for the hyperlinked case) and model-> serializer (for the nested case) which I don't think I'd be very keen on.

The simplest way to do what you need is probably to subclass `ManyRelatedField` and create a custom field type, overriding `to_native(self, obj)` to serialize each object in the set exactly the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check Tom. I haven't asked a type of question which has a 'correct' answer (poor form), but think you've hit the nail more or less on the head. Cheers.