# Reverse URL by more than one parameter in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's take the usual `Customer`s with `Order`s pair of models.

How can we make a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` of `Order` `url` field reverse to a url like `/customers/<customer_pk>/orders/<order_id>/`?

I thought of using the `lookup_field` in the `Meta` class but it seems to only accept one field.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Artur - I'm interested if you solved this? Could you post your own solution?

Comment: @jamesc Sorry, I didn't get around this. I finally had the listing URL like /customers/<customer_pk>/orders/ and the details as /orders/<order_pk>/

Comment: No problem Artur! I found a bit of a work around yesterday - I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

`HyperlinkedModelSerializer` uses a single parameter in the `lookup_field` as of DRF 2.0, so like you, I wasn't able to use this.

However, with some tricks I picked up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448764/django-rest-framework-and-generic-relations) I was able to build a `ModelSerializer` that would have a `url` field that contained the reverse URL as you describe.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Fields, etc
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('make_url')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        # Class info here as usual

    def make_url(self, obj):
        """
        Build URL for Order instance
        """
        # Prepare the IDs you need for the URL reverse
        kwargs = {
            'customer_pk': obj.customer.id,
            'order_id': obj.id,
        }
        url = reverse('api:single_order', kwargs=kwargs)
        return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using viewsets, then this library will help you out: [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I was not using viewsets.

Comment: @ArturSoler Do you use this API endpoint only for reading or for other methods as well?

Comment: Reading, updating and potentially deleting